# Problems rendering a *very* simple partial in a *very* simple app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, renderpartial

**UPDATE:** Feel free to give me negative votes because the issue was that I had named the file _stylesheet.html.erb & not _stylesheets.html.erb. I thought I checked spellings but clearly I did not. I apologize for wasting everyone's time and I appreciate your input.

Hi,

I am learning rails and I started with [Ruby on Rails Tutorial - Learn Rails by Example by Michael Hartl](http://www.railstutorial.org/book). It's a book in progress that he has generously put online. I am currently at the [partials section](http://www.railstutorial.org/chapters/filling-in-the-layout#sec:partials) and I am seeing a weird issue that I have been trying to resolve since last night. I follow the instructions in the partials section but I am getting the following error:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate in Pages#home

Showing app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #6 raised:

Missing layout layouts/_stylesheets.erb in view path app/views
Extracted source (around line #6):

3: <html lang="en" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
4:   <head>
5:     <title><%= title %></title>
6:     <%= render 'layouts/stylesheets' %>
7:   </head>
8:   <body>
9:     <div class="container">
```

Here is the trace:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_view/paths.rb:66:in `find_template'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_view/partials.rb:236:in `_unmemoized__pick_partial_template'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/memoizable.rb:84:in `_pick_partial_template'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_view/partials.rb:184:in `render_partial'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_view/base.rb:276:in `render'
/media/documents/Dropbox/Projects/rails/sample_app/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:6:in `_run_erb_app47views47layouts47application46html46erb'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:34:in `send'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:34:in `render'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_view/base.rb:306:in `with_template'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:30:in `render'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_view/template.rb:205:in `render_template'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_view/base.rb:265:in `render'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_view/base.rb:352:in `_render_with_layout'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_view/base.rb:262:in `render'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1250:in `render_for_file'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/base.rb:945:in `render_without_benchmark'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:51:in `render'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17:in `ms'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17:in `ms'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:51:in `render'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1326:in `default_render'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1332:in `perform_action_without_filters'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:617:in `call_filters'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:610:in `perform_action_without_benchmark'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `perform_action_without_rescue'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17:in `ms'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17:in `ms'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `perform_action_without_rescue'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:160:in `perform_action_without_flash'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/flash.rb:146:in `perform_action'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/base.rb:532:in `send'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/base.rb:532:in `process_without_filters'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:606:in `process'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/base.rb:391:in `process'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/base.rb:386:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:437:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:87:in `dispatch'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:121:in `_call'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:130:in `build_middleware_stack'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:29:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:29:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:34:in `cache'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:9:in `cache'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:28:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:361:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/string_coercion.rb:25:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/head.rb:9:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/params_parser.rb:15:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/session/cookie_store.rb:93:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/failsafe.rb:26:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `synchronize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:114:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/reloader.rb:34:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:108:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/rack/static.rb:31:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:46:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:40:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:40:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/chunked.rb:15:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/handler/mongrel.rb:64:in `process'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:159:in `process_client'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:158:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:158:in `process_client'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `initialize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `new'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `initialize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `new'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/handler/mongrel.rb:34:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/commands/server.rb:111
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
script/server:3
```

What's interesting to me is that I have other projects locally that successfully render partials. So I know it is not a rails version issue (the other project that works does not have rails frozen). I have also checked to see that my partials are in app/views/layouts and that they have an underscore before their name and their extensions are in the right order (.html.erb).

Here is the controller:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    @title = "Home"
  end

  def contact
    @title = "Contact"
  end

  def about
    @title = "About"
  end

  def help
    @title = "Help"
  end
end
```

It's pretty standard stuff and I am not sure why its not working to be honest. Any help in this matter is hugely appreciated.

Thanks!

Ashish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're trying to render a partial, is your partial file prefixed with an underscore?

```
_stylesheets.html.erb
```

Comment: @nowk - Yup. I checked that the first. My partial is named _stylesheets.html.erb and it is located in app/views/layouts.

Comment: Hmm, just to cover all the bases, have you tried restarting your app? I had some issues recently with my development envs not processing new stuff without a restart in 2.3.5.

Comment: @nowk - I'm sorry for not mentioning this before but I tried restarting the server. I even restarted my computer (bad habit from windows) but no success.

Comment: @nowk: I apologize for wasting your time. I realized I had named the file _stylesheet.html.erb & not _stylesheets.html.erb. Rookie, I know!

Answer (score 3):

I really don't know what Rails version you are using but I suggest one of the following:

1. Add the :partial option: `<%= render :partial=>'layouts/stylesheets' %>`(I believe this one would work for you)
2. Rename the file stylesheets.html.erb to stylesheets.erb(I'm not really happy with this one but it might work for you).

Comment: I think he is using version 2.3.5. Look at his logs. I think :partial => 'layouts/stylesheets' thing you mentioned would do the trick for this guy.

Comment: @khelll - Thanks for such a quick response. I failed to mention that I had tried the explicit :partial => call as well with not much success. I have also tried renaming the file to stylesheets.erb instead of stylesheets.html.erb and that did not work as well. The second one not working was expected because that goes against the rails guides and other documentation available out there. 

@DJTripleThreat is correct. I am using rails version 2.3.5 and I am running ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174). Is there any additional information I can provide that might point to why this is happening?

Comment: @khell & @DJTripleThreat: I apologize for wasting your time. I realized I had named the file _stylesheet.html.erb & not _stylesheets.html.erb. Rookie, I know!